# \Zend\Form\Element\Collection validation as a whole

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have form with collection. And i attach validation to whole collecion - i just want to check the existence of certain relations between elements of the collection.

And it works great. in the case of wrong data - form does not pass the "isValid()" test.

But there is one problem. formElementErrors / getMessages didnt return anything.
What i do wrong?

My form:

```
class Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {

        return [
            [
                'name'       => 'legend',
                'required'   => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'validators' => [
                    ['name' => 'Callback', 'options' => [
                        'messages' => [
                            \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Wrong',
                        ],
                        'callback' => function ($values, $context=[]) {
                            return false;
                        },
                    ]],
                ]
            ],


        ];
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name'    => 'legend',
                'type'    => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
                'options' => [
                    'label'                  => 'Legenda',
                    'count'                  => 2,
                    'should_create_template' => true,
                    'allow_add'              => true,
                    'template_placeholder'   => '__placeholder__',
                    'target_element'         => [
                        'type' => 'Narzedzie\Form\Legenda\LegendyOpcjeFieldset',
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And view:

```
    $element = $NarzedzieForm->get('legend');

    var_dump($element->getMessages());  // in case of error - empty array!
    echo $this->formElementErrors($element); // in case of error -  empty string
    echo $this->formColleciton($element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add both messages?

```
'messages' => [
     \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Wrong VALUE',
     \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_CALLBACK => 'Wrong CALLBACK',
 ],
```

as perhaps the invalid callback message is being suppressed as you are only supplying one? I would hope it would fall back to the default. But then all this validator message stuff seems a bit stupid to me the way it is done.

Looks like you have an error in your callback, which might be throwing an exception and is being caught in the validator in the  try catch statement maybe?

should be?

```
function ($values, $context=[]) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if ($value['el'] == '1') return false;
    }
    return true;
},
```

as in $values not $value for the array in the foreach? Probably want to check that key is set too, with an isset($value['el'])?

Comment: i'm sure that this is not error in callback - same situation if i put on callback only "return false/true"; i'm going to check INVALID_CALLBACK. that foreach part is only for example.